# Hyphenation error in pop-up box

Tags: bug, status-completed

I'm a new user on Stack Overflow.

Upon an attempt to vote on a post, I got a polite notice that I didn't have enough reputation to vote.

[image: Typo]

I thought I would report the error: "publicly-displayed" should be written as "publicly displayed." "Publicly" is an adverb ending in -ly, and [adverbs ending in -ly should *not* be hyphenated](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp).

I hope this helps someone today! :)

Comment: Follow up question to the OP; To me the message implies that their vote still impacts the score in some way, is this accurate? If not, could we not simply remove the "publicly-displayed" phrase all together?

Comment: I think you make a valid point. Drawing a distinction by using "publicly displayed" is probably unnecessary for it implies that there are other categories of post scores. Another ambiguity in the sentence is this: does it save votes I cast before 15 reputation and cause them to go into effect once I've reached 15? In my opinion, however, I don't think "change the post score" is the best solution either, and I think the sentence is understood well enough as written (minus the hyphen).

Comment: Related question on [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259583/did-something-change-in-the-behavior-of-blocking-users-votes-if-they-dont-have) about this message.

Comment: @Trobbins The positive or negative vote is stored as "post feedback," but does not affect the actual (displayed) score.  See the link posted by Dronehinge above.

Comment: @jadarnel27 thanks for the notice. Still raises another question; What's the purpose for recording the votes of low (<125) rep users?

Does it affect deletion / VTC scenarios? (ex the case where a post with more than X upvotes is tougher to remove)

Comment: @Trobbins browsing [the post-feedback tag on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=popular&tags=post-feedback), I don't think they're being used for much of anything right now.  In fact, those votes don't look like they've been used for anything since they were implemented in 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was my fault, sorry. :-( The change has been checked in, and will be available as of build 3601 (on MSO and MSE) and 2745 (everywhere else).

Comment: This is a commonly-made mistake, don't sweat it :)

Comment: @CarrieKendall Are you poking a tongue at the OP with regard to "commonly-made" vs "commonly made"? :-P

Comment: I suppose my ironically-satirical comments can often be seen as nanny nanny boo boos (okay, okay.. I'll stop)